# Paypal buy now button places payment on review

Tags: paypal, paypal-buttons

I am using paypal buy now button to accept payments. But after the payment is made by someone it is held under review. I want to be able to accept payment automatically. I have already tried using **paymentaction** variable and getting error

> "Unknown pmtaction value"

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

`paymentaction` can be of three

```
paymentaction  = sale
paymentaction  = authorization
paymentaction  = order
```

Make sure you are using the correct parameter. For instance if you use "paymentaction=authorisation" you will get this error. Use "paymentaction  =authorization".